# Laravel not loading model into route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently developing a PHP Laravel app, and everything has been going well so far. However, my latest resouce called `FreightRequest` is resulting in extremely bizarre behavior that I cannot figure out.

My route file has the following:

`Route::resource('freightrequests', 'FreightRequestController');`

When I access `http://localhost/freightrequests/1`, laravel is not correctly binding the model to my `FreightRequestController@show` method.

My method looks like this:

```
public function show(FreightRequest $freightRequest)
{
    dd($freightRequest);

    return view('freightrequests.show', compact('freightRequest'));
}
```

The above results in the following dump:

```
FreightRequest {#429 ▼
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #events: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}
```

In fact, if I go to a non-existant ID `http://localhost/freightrequests/12343243`, Laravel doesn't throw  `NotFoundHttpException`. If I visit `http://localhost/users/12343243` I get a `NotFoundHttpException`. All of my other resources are working fine except this one resource.

I even tried to ditch the `Route::resource` and replace it with:

`Route::get('freightrequests/{freightrequest}', 'FreightRequestController@show')->name('freightrequests.index');`

I've tried renaming the model, controller, route and everything in case something was conflicting causing Laravel to no retrieve the model. It seems to be injecting the right class instance, but not actually attempting to fetch it from the server. I've tried clearing the cache. I absolutely cannot figure out why this particular model is not working where as my other 6 or so resources are working without issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: looks like there is something wrong with your `FreightRequest`

Comment: Is there a `id` column in the `freight_requests` table?

Answer (score 8):

I found the problem shortly after posting the question:

```
public function show(FreightRequest $freightRequest)
{
   dd($freightRequest);

   return view('freightrequests.show', compact('freightRequest'));
}
```

Should be:

```
public function show(FreightRequest $freightrequest)
{
    dd($freightrequest);

    return view('freightrequests.show', compact('freightrequest'));
}
```

Case-sensitivity matters when trying to bind parameters, and it took me a very long time to realize that R was capital :)

Comment: yeah, i had the same problem - and if you use the artisan command to create a resource controller laravel will even generate the 'wrongly' capitalised variable `$freightRequest`